# Sencha architect 3.0.2 auto sass compiling file not found

Tags: extjs, sass, extjs3

I tried using Sencha Architect 3.0.2. All the sass files are auto compiled and saved. But I cannot find the saved sass files. The new sencha creates all the folder while saving and publishing project but the folders inside sass directory is empty.... Can you suggest me where the files get compiled???

Answer (score 0):

In my installation (Windows 7) the compiled CSS is here:

```
C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Sencha\Sencha Architect 3.0\extracted\ext42-compile\ext-theme-neptune\build\css
```

And the saas code is here:

```
C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Sencha\Sencha Architect 3.0\extracted\ext42-compile\ext-theme-neptune\sass
```

Note that "Administrator" is my user account.

Also note that "AppData" folder is hidden by default.